# How to change position of inherited items in an Inherited user control

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, inheritance, user-controls

I have used a user control as a base class (let's call it BaseUC) with 3 labels (in 3 lines) on it (they are set as protected).

And there is another user control that inherits from it (InheritedUC). I have added two more labels in InheritedUC, which are positioned between the base's labels (so there are 5 lines).

Everything is fine is Visiual Studio's design UI view. But when I run the application, labels on BaseUC overlap with the ones in InheritedUC and I can't see the ones on the inherited control.

Any ideas to fix this? Thank you very much

Comment: Its a designing issue. Related to your html or CSS. Its not an asp.net, C# or inheritance issue.

Comment: You might need to explicitly set the top and left positions, just check what is being rendered/generated now. Or use some kind of a calculated public property in your base class that your child class can also use.

Comment: Thanks ryadavilli. I did set top positions explicitly, in the inherited class. But I was thinking if I could somehow avoid doing that.

Answer (score 1):

From MSDN: [Control.Anchor Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx)

> Use the Anchor property to define how a control is automatically
>   resized as its parent control is resized. **Anchoring a control to its
>   parent control ensures that the anchored edges remain in the same
>   position relative to the edges of the parent control when the parent
>   control is resized.**
>
> You can anchor a control to one or more edges of its container. For
>   example, if you have a Form with a Button whose Anchor property value
>   is set to Top and Bottom, the Button is stretched to maintain the
>   anchored distance to the top and bottom edges of the Form as the
>   Height of the Form is increased.

Set the Anchor property on all labels:
For example:

```
label1.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Left;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you put your controls in a [`FlowLayoutPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.aspx) and set the following options:

```
AutoScroll = True
FlowDirection = TopDown
WrapContents = False
```

Then you should get panel that will grow and shrink as your controls are added or removed.

[Source](http://www.philosophicalgeek.com/2008/12/12/an-easy-stack-layout-panel-for-winforms/)